# Drawing spaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to draw the following spaces:

1. $D_1=\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\leq x\leq 3, -\sqrt{9-x^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{9-x^2}, 0\leq z\leq 2\}$.

   We can write this set also in the form $\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\leq x\leq 3, x^2+y^2=9, 0\leq z\leq 2\}$.

   By $x^2+y^2=9$ we get a circle with center the origin and radius $3$. Since $0\leq x\leq 3$ we consider only the halb of the circle.

   Since $0\leq z\leq 2$ we entend the half of the circle upwards with height $z=2$.

   So, we get the following:

[image]

Is this correct?

- $D_2=\{(x,y,z)\mid 0\leq x\leq 1, \ 1-x\leq y\leq 1, \ x\leq z\leq 1\}$

  By the inequalities $0\leq x\leq 1, \ 1-x\leq y\leq 1$ we get a triangle on the $xy$-plane with vertices $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

  So, we have that triangle at the plane $z=0$. Do we shift that triangle to the plane $z=1$ because of the inequality $x\leq z\leq 1$, and so we get all the points between the triangle at $z=0$ till the triangle at $z=1$ ?
- $D_3$ is defined by the paraboloid with equation $z=2x^2+y^2$ and the cylinder with the equation $z=8-y^2$.

  The paraboloid and the cylinder intersect at $2x^2+y^2=8-y^2 \Rightarrow x^2=4-y^2 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt{4-y^2}$, therefore we get $-\sqrt{4-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{4-y^2}$. 
  It must hold that $4-y^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow y^2\leq 4 \Rightarrow -2\leq y \leq 2$. 
  We have that $2x^2+y^2\leq 2\sqrt{4-y^2}^2+y^2=8-y^2 \Rightarrow 2x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 8-y^2$.

  Therefore the space $D_3$ is the set $\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{4-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{4-y^2}, \ -2\leq y \leq 2, \ 2x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 8-y^2\}$, or not?
- $D_4$ is defined by the surfaces with equations $z=0$, $x^2+2y^2=2$ and $x+y+2z=2$.

  We draw the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=2$ on the $xy$-plane. We extend that ellipse till the plane $x+y+2x=2$.

  Is this correct?
  -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct
2. Notice that at $z=0$ your only allowed $x=0$ since $x\le z$ and $0\le x$. Then $y=1$. So you have a pyramid. 
   [image: Geogebra image]
3. For this, notice that you already calculated $x^2=4-y^2$. That is an equation of a circle, at origin, of radius $2$. Note however that you need to consider $z$ as well. So you need to draw a parabola $z=8-y^2$ on the side of a cylinder
4. OK

Comment: 2. Why do we get a pyramid? At the $xy$-plane ($z=0$) we have that $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: $(0,1,0)$ is only one point. at $z=1$ you get $(0,1,1)$, $(1,0,1)$, and $(1,1,1)$

Comment: Does a pyramid not have a square base? Is this case the base is the defined by the points $(0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)$, or not, which is not a square?

Comment: Do we consider any of the points as the top of the pyramid? Or do we consider the point $(0,1,0)$ ?

Comment: The pyramid has a triangular base, and it's upside down. I've added a picture

Comment: So, $D$ which is on the $xy$-plane is the top of thepyramid and the points $A,B,C$ on the plane $z=1$ consist the basis, right?

Comment: 3. Why do we need to draw a parabola $z=8-y^2$ on the side of a cylinder?

Comment: Which program did you use to sketch that graph?

Comment: I used geogebra

Comment: Ah ok... Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67314/discussion-between-andrei-and-mary-star).